# Golang Determine if String contains a String (with wildcards)

Tags: string, go, search, wildcard

With Go, how would you determine if a string contains a certain string that includes wildcards? Example:

We're looking for `t*e*s*t` (the *'s can be any characters and any length of characters.

`Input True: ttttteeeeeeeesttttttt`

`Input False: tset`

Comment: Use a Regex - but if you really want globbing-style wildcards use a glob library like this one: https://github.com/gobwas/glob

Comment: Updated the formatting of the post.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [regexp](https://godoc.org/regexp) package by converting the `*` in your pattern to the `.*` of regular expressions.

```
// wildCardToRegexp converts a wildcard pattern to a regular expression pattern.
func wildCardToRegexp(pattern string) string {
    var result strings.Builder
    for i, literal := range strings.Split(pattern, "*") {

        // Replace * with .*
        if i > 0 {
            result.WriteString(".*")
        }

        // Quote any regular expression meta characters in the
        // literal text.
        result.WriteString(regexp.QuoteMeta(literal))
    }
    return result.String()
}
```

Use it like this:

```
func match(pattern string, value string) bool {
    result, _ := regexp.MatchString(wildCardToRegexp(pattern), value)
    return result
}
```

[Run it on the Go PlayGround](https://play.golang.org/p/XpLvHQC_Yly).

Comment: Thank you. It appears that this does the trick:

`    package main
    
    import (
     "fmt"
     "regexp"
    )
    
    func main() {
     matched, err := regexp.MatchString(`.*t.*e.*s.*t.*`, "tttteeeessssstttttt")
     fmt.Println(matched, err)
     matched, err = regexp.MatchString(`.*t.*e.*s.*t.*`, "tset")
     fmt.Println(matched, err)
    }`

Answer (score 2):

**Good piece of code**.  I would offer one *minor change*. It seems to me that if you're using wildcards, then the absence of wildcards should mean exact match.  To accomplish this, I use an early return....

```golang
func wildCardToRegexp(pattern string) string {
    components := strings.Split(pattern, "*")
    if len(components) == 1 {
        // if len is 1, there are no *'s, return exact match pattern
        return "^" + pattern + "$"
    }
    var result strings.Builder
    for i, literal := range components {

        // Replace * with .*
        if i > 0 {
            result.WriteString(".*")
        }

        // Quote any regular expression meta characters in the
        // literal text.
        result.WriteString(regexp.QuoteMeta(literal))
    }
    return "^" + result.String() + "$"
}
```

[Run it on the Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/-bdGw-eWAwz)

Comment: the end result should also contain the `"^" + ... + "$"` pattern. Otherwise `test*` also matches `1test`.

Comment: Good catch @RaphaelJenni I've updated the code and playground to include your feedback.